# line charts is higher that the dataset in Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So I have this chart, where I stack the bar/line charts above each others, but I'm doing something wrong, because even a data value which is 5 can be viewed like its up in y=300 if the stacked line chart before was 300.

[image: here]

```js
// Create a canvas into the loaded .php page
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  div = document.getElementById('container');
  canvas.id = "myChart";
  canvas.style.zIndex = 8;
  div.appendChild(canvas);
  const labels = [
      '8',
      '9',
      '11',
      '14',
      '17',
      '21',
      '8',
      '9',
      '11',
      '14',
      '17',
      '21',
  ];

  const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
              label: 'My Fourth dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
              type: 'bar'
          },
          {
              label: 'My Fifth dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,0)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255,255,0)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
              type: 'bar'
          },
          {
              label: 'My Sixth dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,159,64)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255,159,64)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
              type: 'bar'
          },
          {
              label: 'My Seventh dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(224,224,224)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(224,224,224)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
              type: 'bar'
          },
          {
              label: 'My First dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(30,144,255)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(30,144,255)',
              data: [1, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 145, 1, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
              stack: 'combined',
          },
          {
              label: 'My Secound dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(165,42,42)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(165,42,42)',
              data: [1, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 145, 1, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
              stack: 'combined',
          },
          {
              label: 'My Third dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(80,80,80)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(80,80,80)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
          }
      ]
  };

  const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
          plugins: {
              title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'Chart'
              }
          },
          scales: {
              y: {
                  stacked: true
              }
          }
      },
  };
  const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="wdc-canvas-size">
</div>
```

How come my values is displayed like this? I just want each dataset to represent the actually data in the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you don't want stacking all the data in the same group, but the 'stack' parameter is the same for each data set. In the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/samples/bar/stacked-groups.html) the 'stack' parameter identify a Group ID for combining multiple data. I suggest you split the data in different groups.

```js
// Create a canvas into the loaded .php page
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  div = document.getElementById('container');
  canvas.id = "myChart";
  canvas.style.zIndex = 8;
  div.appendChild(canvas);
  const labels = [
      '8',
      '9',
      '11',
      '14',
      '17',
      '21',
      '8',
      '9',
      '11',
      '14',
      '17',
      '21',
  ];

  const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
              label: 'My Fourth dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
              type: 'bar'
          },
          {
              label: 'My Fifth dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,0)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255,255,0)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
              type: 'bar'
          },
          {
              label: 'My Sixth dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,159,64)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255,159,64)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
              type: 'bar'
          },
          {
              label: 'My Seventh dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(224,224,224)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(224,224,224)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined',
              type: 'bar'
          },
          {
              label: 'My First dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(30,144,255)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(30,144,255)',
              data: [1, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 145, 1, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
              stack: 'combined_first',
          },
          {
              label: 'My Secound dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(165,42,42)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(165,42,42)',
              data: [1, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 145, 1, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
              stack: 'combined_second',
          },
          {
              label: 'My Third dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(80,80,80)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(80,80,80)',
              data: [3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8],
              stack: 'combined_third',
          }
      ]
  };

  const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
          plugins: {
              title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'Chart'
              }
          },
          scales: {
              y: {
                  stacked: true
              }
          }
      },
  };
  const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="wdc-canvas-size">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thats right! Is it possible to move the lines infront of the bar charts tho?

Comment: Never mind, just added `order: 1 ....` to them in the order i wanted, so thats perfect thanks!